# ld: framework not found CLTypingLabel

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm getting an error when load the package CLTypingLabel into project,as the picture show.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z5yV9.png)

Comment: the package CLTypingLabel from cocoaPods, the process of install package is no problem, the error occurred open project

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.